# Microsoft 365 developer sandbox login issue incorrect username

Tags: sandbox, microsoft365

Cannot login to a new Microsoft 365 developer sandbox with the admin user created during the provisioning process.

I joined the Microsoft 365 Developer Program with my business account as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program and then setup an instant sandbox following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program-get-started.

I got an email saying that the sandbox has been created and I can see it in the program console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aHz2.png)

When I click in the "Go to subscription" link and try sign-in with admin user I created during the setup I get the incorrect username error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijd1z.png)

We have also tried the same process with another our business accounts and with a personal one and the result has been the same.

It looks like there is some kind of issue generating these sandboxes.

I saw [Error to access my Microsoft 365 instant sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76393523/error-to-access-my-microsoft-365-instant-sandbox), but it does not allow me to comment on that one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [so] is for programming questions. We can't help with account management or billing questions.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved now, there has been an issue when creating  a Microsoft 365 sandbox. If you have this issue and connect to the Developer Center you will see this message:

"If you created your instant sandbox between May 31, 2023 and June 5, 2023, your subscription might have been pre-expired. Please choose Set up subscription to create a new one. For details, see [https://aka.ms/InstantSandboxFAQ."](https://aka.ms/InstantSandboxFAQ.%22)

Creating a new subscription works fine